# Get batches of 5 days from a time frame

Tags: c#

I have records which go over 100 days; I am trying to retrieve 5 days batches until I get to the current day. when I have less than 5 days, then I will retrieve daily records. This is what I have so far:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(-100);    

while (endDate <= startDate)
{
    //do action
    Console.WriteLine("From:" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "  To:" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    endDate = endDate.AddDays(5);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Which outputs the following:

```
From:2018-09-03  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-09-08  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-09-13  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-09-18  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-09-23  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-09-28  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-10-03  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-10-08  To:2018-12-12
From:2018-10-13  To:2018-12-12
...
```

The outcome I want to achieve is:

```
From:2018-09-03  To:2018-09-08
From:2018-09-08  To:2018-09-13
From:2018-09-13  To:2018-09-18
From:2018-09-18  To:2018-09-23
From:2018-09-23  To:2018-09-28
From:2018-09-28  To:2018-10-03
From:2018-10-03  To:2018-10-08
From:2018-10-08  To:2018-10-13
From:2018-10-13  To:2018-12-12
```

Comment: But you know why are you getting such results? Or you completely out of any idea why end dates are those?

Comment: Your `startDate` never changes.

Comment: Why is FROM using endDate and To: using startDate?  Aren't they backwards?

Comment: 5 day.. like Week? Want to group them by Week perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
Console.WriteLine("From:" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "  To:" + endDate.AddDays(5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: If this answer is helpfull, please accept it as answer by checking the green tick

Answer (score 0):

Using Tuple as return type instead of a class you can simply, calculate those date like :

```
var from = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000");
var to = from.AddDays(16);

var result = DateRangePerChunck(from, to, 5);

Console.WriteLine($"Initial range : [FROM: {from.ToShortDateString()}  TO: {to.ToShortDateString()}]");
foreach (var dateRange in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\tFROM: {dateRange.Item1.ToShortDateString()}  TO: {dateRange.Item2.ToShortDateString()}");
}
```

```
public IEnumerable<(DateTime, DateTime)> DateRangePerChunck
    (DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int chunkSize)
{
    var numberOfChunks = (toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days +1 ) / chunkSize;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfChunks; i++)
    {
        if (i == numberOfChunks)
        {
            yield return (fromDate.AddDays(chunkSize * i), toDate);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return (fromDate.AddDays(chunkSize * i), fromDate.AddDays((i + 1) * chunkSize - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
Initial range : [FROM: 01/01/2000    TO: 17/01/2000]

    FROM: 01/01/2000    TO: 05/01/2000
    FROM: 06/01/2000    TO: 10/01/2000
    FROM: 11/01/2000    TO: 15/01/2000
    FROM: 16/01/2000    TO: 17/01/2000
```